# How to update SwiftUI "tintColor" Environment Value

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to create a settings screen where the user can change the tint color of the application. I began by defining the EnvironmentKey

```swift
private struct TintKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue: Color = Color("AccentColor")
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var tintColor: Color {
        get { self[TintKey.self] }
        set { self[TintKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}
```

and then reading the value and attaching it to the main app ContentView.

```swift
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @Environment(\.tintColor) var tintColor

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .tint(tintColor)
        }
    }
}
```

In the SettingsScreen I read the environment tintColor value and pass it to the AppColorsScreen view.

```swift
struct SettingsScreen: View {
    @Environment(\.tintColor) var tintColor

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                NavigationLink { AppColorsScreen(selectedColor: tintColor) } label: { Text("App Color" }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the AppColorsScreen I have a State variable for the selected color and I apply this state variable to set the environment variable when it changes.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct AppColorsScreen: View {
    @State var selectedColor: Color(.green)
    let colors: [(name: String, color: Color)] = [
        ("Red", Color.red),
        ("Green", Color.green),
        ("Blue", Color.blue),
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List(colors, id: \.name) { color in
                HStack {
                    Circle()
                        .fill(Color(color.color))
                        .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
                    Text(color.name)
                    Spacer()
                    if color.color == selectedColor {
                        Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                            .foregroundColor(selectedColor)
                            .bold()
                    }
                }
                .contentShape(Rectangle()) // makes the entire row tappable
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.selectedColor = color.color
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("App Color")
            .environment(\.tintColor, selectedColor)
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    AppColorsScreen
}
```

However, this does not work. The tintColor does not change globally. Only the State variable, `selectedColor`, changes.

Why does this not set the environment value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Environment` isn't really "global". `EnvironmentValues` are

> propagated through a view hierarchy.

So they go from parent to child.

`.environment(\.tintColor, selectedColor)`

Will only propagate to children.

Apple has improved this with `Observable`.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/migrating-from-the-observable-object-protocol-to-the-observable-macro

Here is a working example.

```
import SwiftUI

struct AppColorsScreen: View {
    let colors: [(name: String, color: Color)] = [
        ("Red", Color.red),
        ("Green", Color.green),
        ("Blue", Color.blue),
    ]
    @Environment(AppTheme.self) var theme //Extract the value from the environment
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            @Bindable var theme = theme //Make a two-way connection with the source of truth.
            List(colors, id: \.name) { color in
                HStack {
                    Circle()
                        .fill(Color(color.color))
                        .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
                    Text(color.name)
                        .foregroundStyle(theme.tintColor)
                    Spacer()
                    if color.color == theme.tintColor {
                        Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                            
                            .foregroundColor(theme.tintColor)
                            .bold()
                    }
                }
                .contentShape(Rectangle())
                .onTapGesture {
                    theme.tintColor = color.color
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("App Color")
            
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    @State var theme: AppTheme = .init() //Source of truth
    return AppColorsScreen()
        .environment(theme) //Inject into the Environment
}


@Observable
class AppTheme {
    var tintColor: Color = .red
}

@main
struct MyApp: App {
     @State var theme: AppTheme = .init()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .tint(theme.tintColor)
                .environment(theme) //Inject into the Environment

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your example worked except for I had to change the line under the MyApp struct from `@Environment…` to `@State var theme: AppTheme = .init()`.

Thank you for the explanation about the @Observable macro and the @Bindable var. That is what I was missing.

Comment: @NateBird yes, you are right I missed that edit. Do you mind clicking on the green checkmark and maybe upvoting?